# ruby's nil class' superclass - OOP

Tags: ruby, oop

I may be thinking of this in the wrong way, but this looks kind of weird to me:

I was going through a documentation on [ruby's everything is an object on rubymonk](http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/39-ruby-s-object-model/lessons/128-behaviour) and got to the part about superclass, with the following example:

```
p Foo.superclass
p Foo.superclass.superclass
p Foo.superclass.superclass.superclass
```

Where `Foo` is a class, and got the following:

```
STDOUT:

Object
BasicObject
nil
```

I was kind of confused why the last one was a `nil` and I went ahead on checking:

```
p Foo.superclass.superclass.superclass.superclass
```

which would have been an equivalent of `p nil.superclass`, and I got the following error:

```
undefined method `superclass' for nil:NilClass
```

And when I tried the following, I got more confused:

[image]

Why will I be able to call `superclass` on `Foo`, and not on `nil`, when I can call superclass on each of their class respectively(`Class` and `NilClass`) - `Foo` and `nil` are both instances of some other `class` which has `superclass`es.

What is special about `nil`? what got missing between `nil` and `NilClass` that `NilClass` will have a `superclass`, and `nil` wont have one?

Answer (score 2):

In the case of `BasicObject`, the return value of `nil` does *not* indicate the superclass. It indicates the *absence* of a superclass. `nil` is not a class (`nil` is an instance of `NilClass`, classes are instances of `Class`), it is an object that represents the idea of "absence".

Only classes have superclasses. Things which aren't classes don't have cuperclasses. Since `nil` is not a class, it doesn't have a superclass. There are tons of other things that don't have superclasses: `1` doesn't have a superclass. `'Hello'` doesn't have a superclass. `[]` doesn't have a superclass. In fact, not only do those objects not have superclasses, the very idea of a superclass isn't even meaningful for them.

`nil` is an instance of `NilClass`, `NilClass` doesn't define a `superclass` instance method and neither does any of its ancestors (`Object`, `Kernel`, `BasicObject`).

Being an instance of `Class`, `NilClass` *does* respond to a `superclass` message (because `Class` defines a `superclass` instance method), and its superclass is `Object`.

So, we have two different interpretations of a missing superclass here:

- `BasicObject` responds with `nil` when you ask it about its superclass, because it doesn't have one. But it is still a class, and for classes, the question about a superclass makes sense, which is why it will answer your question, but tell you "no, I don't have one".
- `nil`, `1`, and all the other objects which aren't classes, will even refuse to answer your question, because the idea of them having a superclass doesn't make sense.

Comment: `NilClass` _does_ have a superclass, though

Comment: Sure, all classes except one have a superclass. But the question was "what makes `nil` special", and the answer is: `nil` isn't special in having no superclass, in fact, almost all objects have no superclass, only classes have superclasses.

Comment: Yes. Then how does this combine with the last sentence of the answer?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I don't see any contradiction.

Comment: "NilClass doesn't have a superclass method", "all classes except one have a superclass", `NilClass.superclass # => Object`

Comment: I still don't see any contradiction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94696/discussion-between-sergio-tulentsev-and-jorg-w-mittag).

Answer (score 0):

```
Foo.superclass.superclass.superclass
```

Is effectively calling the `superclass` method of the [fundamental object `BasicObject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/BasicObject.html).

`BasicObject` has no superclass, so the method returns `nil`

`nil` is an instance of the `NilClass`, so not a class in itself.

If you call `nil.class.superclass`, you get `Object`